# Why not start selenium standalon server as the user jenkins?

Tags: ubuntu, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

There are two user jehord and jenkins
Running tests from the command console produced nightwatch
If a start is made from a user jehord then all is well, but if the switch and run tests from a user jenkins I get an error

```
> Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server { sessionId:
> null,   status: 13,   state: 'unhandled error',   value:     {
> supportUrl: null,
>      screen: null,
>      additionalInformation: '\nDriver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver',
>      hCode: 1457029,
>      buildInformation: 
>       { releaseLabel: '2.45.0',
>         buildTime: '2015-02-26 23:59:50',
>         class: 'org.openqa.selenium.internal.BuildInfo',
>         buildRevision: '5017cb8',
>         hCode: 13974215 },
>      systemInformation: 'System info: host: \'jehord-VirtualBox\', ip: \'127.0.1.1\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'i386\', os.version:
> \'3.13.0-32-generic\', java.version: \'1.7.0_79\'',
>      class: 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException',
>      cause: null,
>      localizedMessage: 'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248316,platform=Linux
> 3.13.0-32-generic x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)\nCommand duration or timeout: 60.62
> seconds\nBuild info: version: \'2.45.0\', revision: \'5017cb8\', time:
> \'2015-02-26 23:59:50\'\nSystem info: host: \'jehord-VirtualBox\', ip:
> \'127.0.1.1\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'i386\', os.version:
> \'3.13.0-32-generic\', java.version: \'1.7.0_79\'\nDriver info:
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver',
>      message: 'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248316,platform=Linux
> 3.13.0-32-generic x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)\nCommand duration or timeout: 60.62
> seconds\nBuild info: version: \'2.45.0\', revision: \'5017cb8\', time:
> \'2015-02-26 23:59:50\'\nSystem info: host: \'jehord-VirtualBox\', ip:
> \'127.0.1.1\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'i386\', os.version:
> \'3.13.0-32-generic\', java.version: \'1.7.0_79\'\nDriver info:
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver',
>      suppressed: [ [length]: 0 ] },   class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',   hCode: 24277937 }
> 
> Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
```

What is the problem?